# ApnsPHP error, in my codeigniter project

Tags: php, codeigniter, apple-push-notifications

I'm having this error when i send a form with codeigniter, I wasn't having this problem before. I was just checking my entire project and notice this query wasn't doing good.
Some help? Thanks

```
Mon, 16 Mar 2015 12:11:32 -0430 ApnsPHP[4156]: ERROR: Unable to send message ID 1: Invalid token (8).
Mon, 16 Mar 2015 12:11:33 -0430 ApnsPHP[4156]: WARNING: Message ID 1 [custom identifier: unset] has an unrecoverable error (8), removing from queue without retrying...
Mon, 16 Mar 2015 12:11:34 -0430 ApnsPHP[4156]: ERROR: Unable to send message ID 2: Invalid token (8).
Mon, 16 Mar 2015 12:11:35 -0430 ApnsPHP[4156]: WARNING: Message ID 2 [custom identifier: unset] has an unrecoverable error (8), removing from queue without retrying...
```

Controller:

```
public function add_notificacion() {
    $data = array();
    if (!empty($this->input->post('mensaje', TRUE))) {

        if (($this->input->post('id_profesor', TRUE) != 0)) {
            $id_profesor = $this->input->post('id_profesor', TRUE);
            $this->load->model('Profesor_model', 'profesor');
            $json_data = $this->profesor->gets_profesor($id_profesor);
            foreach ($json_data as $fila) {
                $nivel[] = $fila->id_nivel;
            }
        } else {
            $nivel = $this->input->post('niveles', TRUE);
        }
        if (!empty($this->input->post('fecha_notificacion', TRUE))) {
            $date = $this->input->post('fecha_notificacion', TRUE);
            $date_formate = str_replace("/", "-", $date);
            $fecha_notificacion = date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime($date_formate));
        } else {
            $fecha_notificacion = '';
        }
        date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
        $fecha = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
        $nino = $this->input->post('nino', TRUE);
        $res = $this->notificacion->representante($nino);
        foreach ($res as $item){
            $representante[] = $item->id_representante;
        }
        $notificacion_data = array(
            'mensaje' => $this->input->post('mensaje', TRUE),
            'titulo' => $this->input->post('titulo', TRUE),
            'id_nivel' => $nivel,
            'fecha_notificacion' => $fecha_notificacion,
            'fecha' => $fecha,
            'tipo' => $this->input->post('tipo', TRUE),
            'id_profesor' => $this->input->post('id_profesor', TRUE),
            'id_colegio' => $this->input->post('id_colegio', TRUE)
        );
        if (!empty($notificacion_data)) {
            $this->notificacion->add_notificacion($notificacion_data, $representante);
            $dato = array("message" => "Se agrego la notificación exitosamente");
        } else {
            $dato = array("message1" => "Error al intentar agregar notificación");
        }
        $this->load->view('notificacion/add_notificacion', $dato);
    }else{

    $valor = $this->session->userdata("verified");
    if (!empty($valor)) {
        if (($valor["id_colegio"]) != 0) {
            $id_colegio = $valor["id_colegio"];
            $data["nivel"] = $this->notificacion->obtener_nivel($id_colegio, 0);
        }
        if (!empty($valor["id_profesor"])) {
            $id_profesor = $valor["id_profesor"];
            $this->load->model('Profesor_model', 'profesor');
            $result = $this->profesor->gets_profesor($id_profesor);
            $id_colegio = $result[0]->id_colegio;
            $id_nivel = $result[0]->id_nivel;
            $data["nivel"] = $this->notificacion->obtener_nivel($id_colegio, $id_nivel);

        }
    }
    $this->load->view('notificacion/add_notificacion', $data);
}
```

}

Model:

```
 public function add_notificacion($notificacion_data, $representante) {
    $keys_ios = $keys_android = array();
    $j = 0;

    foreach ($notificacion_data["id_nivel"] as $item) {
        $notificacion_data["id_nivel"] = $item;
        $array[] = $item;
    }
    $count = count($array);
    unset($notificacion_data["id_nivel"]);
    $this->db->insert('notificaciones', $notificacion_data);
    $id_notificacion = (int) $this->db->insert_id();

    if (empty($representante)) {
        $query = "SELECT id_representante FROM `representante` left join nino_padre using (id_representante) left join nino using (id_nino) where id_nivel IN (" . implode(",", $array) . ") group by (id_representante)";
        $result = $this->db->query($query);
        $tmp = $result->result();
        $count = count($tmp);

        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            foreach ($tmp[$i] as $valor) {
                $representante[] = $valor;
            }
        }
    }

    foreach ($representante as $valor) {
        $data["id_notificacion"] = $id_notificacion;
        $data["id_representante"] = $valor;
        if ($j < $count) {
            $data["id_nivel"] = $array[$j];
        }
        $this->db->insert('notificacion_representante', $data);
        $j++;
    }
    $this->email($representante, $notificacion_data);
    $query = "SELECT key_ios, key_android FROM users ";
    $query .= "where id_representante IN (" . implode(",", $representante) . ")";
    $result = $this->db->query($query)->result();

    foreach ($result as $item) {

        if (!empty($item->key_ios)) {
            $keys_ios[] = $item->key_ios;
        }
        if (!empty($item->key_android)) {
            $keys_android[] = $item->key_android;
        }
    }

    if (!empty($keys_ios)) {
        $this->push->push_notificacion_ios($keys_ios);
    }
    if (!empty($keys_android)) {
        $this->push->push_notificacion_android($keys_android);
    }
}
```

Comment: Btw, the data is getting insert into the db. But that error appears in my screen

Comment: can you share your code? have you changed any db fields or the model?

Comment: i changed some database field, just adding UNIQUEs fields and NOT NULL fields, do u think that could make this error appears?

Comment: yes, you need to add that to the models telling that its been modified, add UNIQUE and NOT NULL field changes to the models. Save the models and re-run your app. The db errors should go away.

Comment: well, im doing the backend for this app so im not touching any iOS code, but i replace the DB for a backup i did before changing fields in my DB. its not working anyway. i didnt change anything in the code, just the fields in db.

Comment: Your token is bad. Error is very clear `Invalid token (8).`

Comment: I know bro, as I said, im not an iOS developder, im just doing the backend of this app. I just dont know how to fix this. If you can help me out here i'll appreciate. Thanks

Comment: It looks like you have some invalid push tokens in your database. Apple can revoke or change a device's token at any time, when they do they respond with an error so that the web application knows to remove the token from the database. This can also happen if you had devices register via the sandbox and you try to send via the production service (or vice versa).